# Can two repositories share the same unit of work?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, architecture, prism

In my project I have two tabs and in `ViewManager` class i have following code to add register those views with region ,

```
IBondsUnitOfWork UnitOfWork = new BondsUnitOfWork(new TestEntities(DALUtilities.ProjConnectionString));

IRepo1 repo = new Repo1(UnitOfWork);

IRepo2 repo_second = new Repo2(UnitOfWork);
```

My question is can I use same `UnitOfWork` for different repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no restriction for doing it. You are getting control of your data access in a level above, which is good when you access some repositories and does some tasks like `insert`, `update`, `delete`. Just a pseudo-code sample, for sample:

```
IBondsUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new BondsUnitOfWork(new TestEntities(DALUtilities.ProjConnectionString));

try
{
   unitOfWork.Open();
   unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

   IRepo1 repo = new Repo1(unitOfWork);

   repo.Update(obj);

   IRepo2 repo_second = new Repo2(unitOfWork);

   repo.Add(obj2);

   unitOfWork.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   unitOfWork.RollBack();
   // catch exception here...
   // log..
}
finally
{
   unitOfWork.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I was thinking as they are using same context it will affect both the tabs.

Comment: No will not, but make sure you have control about the context.